# Dreamweaver Postback with Classic asp

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I am attempting to create a 4-way filter method for the inventory of my company. I am currently using Dreamweaver CS6, Classic ASP via VBScript, javascript, and jquery.The website is here (http://www.steeltradingcorp.com/Connections/manage_invent3.asp). I now have the filters working, but asynchronously when I use OR in the recordset. If I use AND, then the form doesn't let the table display until all options are filled(like it's supposed to). On an off-note, should I close this question since I keep changing it? This is the current coding:

```
Set Recordset1_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Recordset1_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_Inventory_STRING
Recordset1_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblMKTInvExportGroups WHERE [Size] = ? AND 
[Wall] = ? AND [Grade] = ? AND [Status] = ?"

<%
dim OD
dim WaT
dim Gra
dim Sta

OD=Request.Form("OD")
WaT=Request.Form("WaT")
Gra=Request.Form("Gra")
Sta=Request.Form("Sta")
%>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="manage_invent.asp" method="post" name="Search" id="Search">
Choose your OD:<select name="OD" id="OD" size="1" >
    <option value="<%=OD%>"><%=OD%></option>
  <%
While (NOT getSize.EOF)
%>
  <option value="<%=(getSize.Fields.Item("Size").Value)%>">
<%=(getSize.Fields.Item("Size").Value)%></option>
  <%
  getSize.MoveNext()
Wend
If (getSize.CursorType > 0) Then
  getSize.MoveFirst
Else
  getSize.Requery
End If
%>
</select>
<br/>Choose your Wall:
<input name="WaT" id="WaT" type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" value="<%=WaT%>"/><br/>
Choose your Grade:<select name="Gra" id="Gra" size="1">
  <option value="<%=Gra%>"><%=Gra%></option>
  <%
While (NOT getGrade.EOF)
%>
  <option value="<%=(getGrade.Fields.Item("Grade").Value)%>">
<%=(getGrade.Fields.Item("Grade").Value)%></option>
  <%
  getGrade.MoveNext()
Wend
If (getGrade.CursorType > 0) Then
  getGrade.MoveFirst
Else
  getGrade.Requery
End If
%>
</select>
<br/>Choose your Status:<select name="Sta" id="Sta" size="1">
  <option value="<%=Sta%>"><%=Sta%></option>
  <%
While (NOT getStatus.EOF)
%>
  <option value="<%=(getStatus.Fields.Item("status").Value)%>">
<%=(getStatus.Fields.Item("status").Value)%></option>
  <%
  getStatus.MoveNext()
Wend
If (getStatus.CursorType > 0) Then
  getStatus.MoveFirst
Else
  getStatus.Requery
End If
%>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" onClick="showCho" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to put an if statement or Select Case into the Commandtext? I tried a version that was based off asp/javascript, but my page went completely blank with no error messages. I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: I don't think you're going to want to run a SQL statement that's coming from the client/JavaScript.

Comment: If there's a page refresh involved anyway, i.e. a round-trip to the server, then why do you need JavaScript? Just get the values from the form in your VBScript.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't managed to do this. When the user selects 5.5 size from the dropdown and hits submit, then chooses from the text box, it returns 5.5, 5.0, and 7.625. I would like it to return just 5.5. Perhaps I don't understand the recordset parameters very well, I'll read more about them.

Comment: I don't understand: what is the user choosing from the text box, and what is returning those values? I did notice that you're specifying neither the `action` nor the `method` of the forms; I believe the `action` defaults to the current page, but I don't offhand know whether the `method` has a default, and if so, what. Also, idle curiosity perhaps, but what's with the odd field names? Wouldn't your code be more readable if you could access the first name field using `Request.Form("FirstName")` rather than `Request.Form("forth")`?

Comment: Sorry, the user would be choosing the Wall thickness that goes with his choice of OD Size(1.9 and up). It's pipe casing. I've gone back and forth with Post and get, I prefer post. The odd field names are from me grabbing code from the Internet and trying to make them work. My training only included HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. This job is the first time I've done dynamic websites. It's a Windows Server with IIS6, and I was told PHP wouldn't work with it.

Comment: I would encourage you to first update your variable and object names to be meaningful in their current context... it will help but you and us to see what's happening. Second, the top code appears to be receiving the form post, then querying DB for product info, placing that recordset into Recordset1, then doing nothing with the recordset on the server side, where the data IS, but using client-side javascript to write a value we haven't seen you define. You can Response.Write the RS data on the server side to send it to the client without using any javascript at all.

Comment: I've edited it with my current coding. I think I jumped into the deep end of the pool before learning how to swim, though.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was separating the inventory into four pages to eliminate one option, and another was said to be unneeded. The two remaining options were copied across all four pages and consisted of four recordsets for the dropdowns and four for the tables. Then I used show and hide region to display a different form and table depending on how the form was filled.

http://www.steeltradingcorp.com/